# Show $k\mid n^2\Rightarrow k\mid n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We know that $k | n^2$ . How we can prove that $k | n$ ? ($n$ and $k$ are Natural numbers [update: and also $k$ is prime number]

My try : I can prove it in special cases for example $k = 5$ using contradiction but I can't generalize it.

Comment: Hint: $\ n^2\mid n^2\ $ but $\,n^2\nmid n\ $ if $\,n> 1\ \ $

Comment: If there are no further assumptions, the statement is false. $4\mid 4$ however $4\not\mid 2$.

Comment: Perhaps these "special cases" are the cases that $k$ is prime, or a product of different primes.

Comment: I think you are right .

Comment: If $k$ is not squarefree then there is an integer $n$ such that $k\mid n^2$ but $k\nmid n$. However if $k$ is squarefree, then $k\mid n^2 \implies k\mid n$

Comment: Can you explain your answer completely ?

Comment: By definition of prime element $p$ we have the $p$ devides a product $ab$ iff it divides $a$ or $b$. Now take $a=b=n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume for the sake of contradiction that $k\nmid n$. Note $n = p_1^{a_1}\times p_2^{a_2}\times p_3^{a_3}...{p_m}^{a_m}$ (ie the prime factorization), so $n^2 = p_1^{2n_1}\times p_2^{2n_2}\times p_3^{2n_3}...{p_m}^{2a_m}$. If $k$ is prime, and $k$ divides $n^2$, then $k = p_i, 1 \leq i \leq a_m$. However, we note that $n = q * p_i$, where $q \in \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore $p_i | n$, so $k | n$. This yields a contradiction.

Essentially, the proof follows from the fact that $n$ and $n^2$ have the same prime factors. Hope this helps!

Comment: I think your solution is complete . Thank You!

Comment: Can we deduct if $k| n^j $ and $j \ge 2$ then $k | n$ ?

Comment: @S.H.W provided that $k$ is prime, I believe so. The proof should follow similarly to above, just replace all instances of squaring a number with raising it to the $j$-th power instead.

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample: $4\mid 2^2$.

Usually this assumes that $k$ is prime. In general, if $(a,b) = 1$ and $a\mid bc$, then $a\mid c$. This can be done with Bezout, by taking $x$ and $y$ such that $ax + by = 1$, implying $axc + byc = c$. But then $c$ is the sum of two numbers that divide $a$, so it does as well. Now, assume $p$ is prime and $p\mid ab$, then either $p\mid a$, or $(a,p) = 1$, so by the previous discussion, $p\mid b$. Now you get your result (there may be generalizations of this, but this is the typical version seen as far as I know).

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a prime number $k$ is one such that
$$k\mid (a\cdot b) \implies k\mid a \text{ or }k\mid b$$

Therefore, if $k \mid n^2 = (n\cdot n)$ then $k\mid n$ or $k\mid n$.

---

Now if $k$ is squarefree then $k = \displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^r p_i$ for some family of prime numbers $p_i$. If $k\mid n^2$ then $p_i\mid n^2$ and by what we just proved above, $p_i\mid n$. Since this is true for all $p_i$ ($i=1,\ldots,r$) and $\gcd(p_i,p_j) = 1$ iff $i\neq j$ then

$$\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^r p_i \mid n$$

i.e. $k\mid n$.

---

Now if $k$ is not squarefree, then there are integers $m,t$ (where $t > 1$) such that $k = mt^2$. In that case taking $n = mt$ one haves $k\mid n^2 = m^2t^2 = mk$ but $k\nmid n$.

Comment: Can we deduct if $k| n^j $ and $j \ge 2$ then $k | n$ ?

Comment: If $k$ is prime then you can use the same reasoning with induction on $j$: $k\mid n^j \implies k\mid n$ or $k\mid n^{j-1}$. One can then adapt the resoning for any squarefree $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the prime factorization
$$
n = \prod p_i^{e_i}
$$
we have
$$
n^2 = \prod p_i^{2e_i}
$$
If $k$ is a prime number we have
$$
k = p_j^1
$$
for some $j$.
Then $k \mid n^2$ means
$$
1 \le 2e_j  \quad (*)
$$
while $k \mid n$ would mean
$$
1 \le e_j \quad (**)
$$
From $(*)$ we take
$$
\frac{1}{2} \le e_j
$$
so $e_j > 0$ which implies $e_j \ge 1$ for integer $e_j$. But this is condition $(**)$, so $k \mid n$ as well.

Comment: But I think we must write $k$  just as $p_i$

Comment: Ok, I see you edited your question. I edited my answer as well.